# Почему не работает if else?

Tags: python, if

код:

```
import numexpr
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
init()

for k in range(3):
    print(Fore.CYAN)
    user_password=input("Введите пароль:")
    password=123
    if password==user_password:
        print(Fore.BLUE)
        print("Доступ разрешён.")
        for i in range(1):
        
            print(Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX)
        
            expr = input("Введите математическое выражение: ")
            result = numexpr.evaluate(expr)
        
            print(Fore.GREEN)
        
            print(f"Результат: {result}")
        
        print(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX)
        print("Лимит использования превышен!!!")
    else:
        print(Fore.RED)
        print("Доступ запрещён!!!")
```

в терминале:

```
Введите пароль:123
Доступ запрещён!!!
```

Comment: И при чём тут VSCode?

Comment: Я делал с YouTube видео; программа должна была запустить цикл (калькулятор) через пароль (123) но не запустила, почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
    user_password=input("Введите пароль:")
    password=123
    if password==user_password:
```

`input` всегда возвращает строку. Вы сравниваете строку с числом, это сравнение никогда не даст положительный результат. Сравнивайте две строки:

```py
    user_password=input("Введите пароль:")
    password='123' # теперь это строка
    if password==user_password:
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это сработало.

Answer (score 0):

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

for k in range(3):
    print(Fore.CYAN)
    user_password = input("Введите пароль:")
    password = "123"
    if user_password == password:
        print(Fore.BLUE)
        print("Доступ разрешён.")
        for i in range(1):
            print(Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX)

            expr = input("Введите математическое выражение: ")
            result = numexpr.evaluate(expr)

            print(Fore.GREEN)

            print(f"Результат: {result}")

        print(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX)
        print("Лимит использования превышен!!!")
    else:
        print(Fore.RED)
        print("Доступ запрещён!!!")

user_password=input("Введите пароль:")
    password=123
    if password==user_password:
```

> При вводе данных input всегда придаёт значение str. в Python
> невозможно сравнивать разные типы данных, значит мы должны изменить
> тип данных 123 - int на "123" str: password = "123" - тип данных str

Answer (score -1):

Если пароль всегда из цифр, то `user_password=(int)input("Введите пароль:")`

Comment: Вроде и да, но если пользователь случайно введёт букву, то код выкинет исключение, его (это исключение) по-хорошему нужно тогда ловить.

Comment: Это синтаксически некорректное выражение, в Python приведение типов в стиле Си не работает.